# How to add a parent ID to every child in a array? php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting, hierarchy

Hi guys I was wondering how can I add a parent ID in the children?

Ex: MY_ARRAY

```
(
[id] => 4
[children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 21
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 22
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 19
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 26
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

And as of now these are the codes that I did but still not giving me the correct result.

```
$in = MY_ARRAY
function generateArray($in, $out, $parent = 0, $prev_par = 0){
    foreach($in as $key => $value) {
        $childs = false;
        if(isset($value['children'])){ // if there is children
            $childs = $value['children'];
            unset($value['children']);              
        }
        if($prev_par != $parent){
            $prev_par = $parent;
        }
        else{
            $prev_par = $prev_par;
        }
        $out[] = array($value['id'],$parent,$prev_par);
        if($childs){
            $parent = $value['id'];
            $out = $this->generateArray($childs, $out, $parent, $prev_par);
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

---

I would need to add an Parent ID becaue as of now it I can retrive their heirarchy without displaying correnct Parent ID.

The output could look like this. As long as I can add the Parent ID.

```
[id] => 4
[P_id] => 0
[children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18
                [P_id] => 4
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 21
                                [P_id] => 18
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 22
                                [P_id] => 18
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 19
                [P_id] => 4
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [P_id] => 4
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 26
                                [P_id] => 20
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Need really help here thanks guys...

Comment: Share your `$in` array that is function's first param.

Comment: sure will update it @AHJeebon is MY_ARRAY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Your problem is solved, check it. The function is recursively push
>   `p_id` and another point is if the array contain numeric index then
>   it will skip to push `p_id`.

**Function is:**

```
function generateArray($in, $parent = 0){
  foreach ($in as $key => $value) {
    if(is_numeric($key)){
        $in = $value;
        $out[$key] = generateArray($in, $parent);
    }else{
      $out[$key]=$value;
      if($key=="id"){
        $out['p_id']=$parent;
        $parent=$value;
      }elseif($key=="children"){
        $in = $value;
        $out[$key] = generateArray($in, $parent);
      }
    }
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Working example:

```
$my_array =array(
  'id'=> 4,
  'children'=> Array(
    '0'=> Array(
      'id'=> 18,
      'children'=> Array(
          '0'=> Array(
            'id'=> 21,
          ),
          '1'=> Array(
            'id'=> 22,
          ),
        ),
    ),
    '1'=> Array(
      'id'=> 19,
    ),
    '2'=> Array(
      'id'=> 20,
      'children'=> Array(
        '0'=> Array(
          'id'=> 26,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
);

$newarray = generateArray($my_array);
print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: Do you have any reference creating that function?

Comment: I took some time to create this function. But i have followed some example form here: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: Thanks will check that link also! :D

Comment: hi! I was trying to and incremental value after [p_id] which is [inc]

Comment: [id] => 4
[P_id] => 0
[inc] => 1
[children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 18
                [P_id] => 4
                [inc] => 2
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 21
                                [P_id] => 18
                                [inc] => 3
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 19
                [P_id] => 4
                [inc] => 5
)